# $\{\alpha < \kappa \mid cf(\alpha) = \lambda\}$ is not ineffable

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

We call a subset $X \subseteq \kappa$ of a regular cardinal $\kappa$ ineffable, iff for every family $(A_\alpha \mid \alpha \in X)$ of subsets $A_\alpha \subseteq \alpha$, there is a stationary set $S \subseteq X$, such that $A_\alpha = A_\beta \cap \alpha$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in S$ with $\alpha \le \beta$.
Now, $\{\alpha < \kappa \mid cf(\alpha) = \lambda\}$ is claimed not to be ineffable, where $\lambda < \kappa$ is a regular cardinal.

Can anyone give me a hint how to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** For each $\alpha\in\{\alpha<\kappa\mid\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)=\lambda\}$ pick $A_\alpha$ to be a cofinal sequence of order type $\lambda$. If $\alpha<\beta$, can $A_\beta\cap\alpha$ be equal to $A_\alpha$?

Comment: Oh, I see. If $\alpha < \beta$ and $A_\beta \cap \alpha = A_\alpha$, then $A_\beta \cap \alpha$ has order type $\lambda$, so $A_\beta = A_\beta \cap \alpha$, which contradicts the cofinality of $A_\beta$ in $\beta$, right?

Comment: Yeah. Or in simpler word, a well order is never order isomorphic to any of its proper initial segments.